# can i create a exam generator using php language?

Tags: php

Hi i would like to ask is it possible to create an exam generator which will randomly retrieve questions from the database in php language? I would like to confirm whether is it doable since i'm doing my final year project.

Comment: sry fairly new to stackoverflow, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, PHP has all the functions needed to select items and random from an array of all possible questions.

PHP also gives you all the tools you need to store and retrieve records from a database, and the functions to compute statistics.

There are extensions that can be used to perform just about any programming task, including advanced computations...

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is Turing-comlete and has random number and database support, yes.

Comment: is it hard to execute this kind of project , i am fairly new to this language